# Mandrill merge variables for CC recipients not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill's NodeJS [Messages API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.nodejs.html) to send emails, using merge_vars to be able to reuse the same templates easily for all recipients, and group messages in batches.

While merge_vars work fine with the main recipient, they don't resolve for CC or BCC recipients, being showed as `*|merge_var_name|*` instead of the actual value.

Is this an inherent limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Mandrill provides two different ways to merge variables - you are apparently using the per-recipient option "merge_vars".  The "global_merge_vars" option will perform the substitution for all recipients.  Details available at https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.nodejs.html